# If $f$ is Riemann integrable, what conditions imply that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Here is the exercise from my textbook. I have already solved the problem, but I want to ask another question regarding the statement that needed to be proven.

> Suppose $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable. Define $F: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
> $$F(t) = \begin{cases}0~~~\textrm{if $t=a$,} \\ \int_{a}^{t}f~~~ \textrm{if $t \in (a,b]$.} \end{cases}$$

Prove that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

If $F(t) \neq 0$ when $t = a$, then I think that $F$ will no longer be continuous because the indefinite integral $\int_{a}^{t}f$ will not converge for every $\epsilon > 0$, but I don't feel like I can formulate a good enough argument to convince myself and my friend. Is my proposition true?

Comment: Do you mean the indefinite integral $\int_a^{a+\epsilon}f$? Or what? (And in any case, this integral converges for all $\epsilon>0$.)

Comment: Isn't fulfilled $\int_{a}^{a}=0$?

Comment: As @zkutch points out, there’s no need to define $F(a)$ separately. It just confuses the issue.

Comment: The exercise was being sneaky :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|F(t)| \leq M(t-a)$ for $a <t \leq b$ where $M$ is a bounded for $|f|$. Hence $F(t) \to 0$ as $t \to a+$. So for $F$ to be continuous it is essential that $F(a)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me say, that for $t=a$ should be $F(a)=0$ is not something extraordinary, but comes from definition by integral. For any $c \in (a,b)$ in same manner should be $F(c)=\int\limits_{a}^{c}f(x)\,dx$, or $F$ will not be continuous. To prove is enough consider
$$F(c+\Delta x)-F(c)=\int\limits_{c}^{c+\Delta x}f(x)\,dx= \mu \Delta x$$ which tends to $0$.